# Cant resolve an issue with an infinite loop in a chat app

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I'm building a chat app...while init the chat page I'm checking for messages and storing in a message array

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.messageService.getMessages().doc(`${this.sortItineraries[0] + '-' + this.sortItineraries[1]}`)
    .onSnapshot((doc) => {
      console.log('init message.page in snapshot', doc.data().message);
      this.messages = [];
      this.messages = doc.data();
      console.log('init message.page variable', this.messages);
    });
  }
```

The infinite loop is caused when I send a message with the following code

```js
  getMessages() {
    return this.allMessages;
  }

  getAllMessages() {
    return this.allMessages;
  }

  async createMessage(itineraries) {
    console.log('createMessage');
      const docRef = await firebase.firestore().doc(`messages/${itineraries}`).set({
      message: []
    });
  }

  async sendMessage(id, content, userId) {

    this.allMessages.doc(`${id}`)
    .onSnapshot((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log('sendmessage doc exists');
        this.send(id, content, userId);
      } else {
        this.createMessage(id)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('sendmessage !doc exists');
          this.send(id, content, userId);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  async send(id, content, userId) {
    console.log('send');
    const uid = this.loggedInUser.uid;
    const ref = this.afs.collection('messages').doc(id);
    return ref.update({
      message: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
        content,
        createdAt: Date.now(),
        userId
      })
    });
  }
```

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-list lines="none">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let message of messages.message">
      <div size="9" *ngIf="myItinerary.userId !== message.userId" class="message other-user">
        <span>{{message.content}}</span>
        <div class="time" text-right><br>
        {{message.createdAt | date: 'short'}}</div>
        </div>

      <div offset="3" size="9" *ngIf="myItinerary.userId === message.userId" class="message me" slot="end">
        <span>{{message.content}}</span>
        <div class="time" text-right><br>
        {{message.createdAt | date: 'short'}}</div>
        </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar light="light">
    <ion-row align-items-center no-padding>
      <ion-col size="8">
        <textarea autosize maxRows="3" [(ngModel)]="newMsg" class="message-input"></textarea>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="3">
        <ion-button expand="block" fill="clear" color="primary" [disabled]="newMsg === ''" class="msg-btn"
        (click)="sendMessage()">
        <ion-icon name="ios-send" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

[image: Console Log]

The screenshot shows the console logs in which it loops between the service that creates and sends the messages to the firebase backend and the init.  It keeps looping until i exit the app and delete the messages in firebase.

What I do in the service is check if the doc is created

```js
 async sendMessage(id, content, userId) {

    this.allMessages.doc(`${id}`)
    .onSnapshot((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log('sendmessage doc exists');
        this.send(id, content, userId);
      } else {
        this.createMessage(id)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('sendmessage !doc exists');
          this.send(id, content, userId);
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

If it doesn't exist then I create it before pushing the messages to the message array in firebase

```js
  async createMessage(itineraries) {
    console.log('createMessage');
      const docRef = await firebase.firestore().doc(`messages/${itineraries}`).set({
      message: []
    });
  }
  
    async send(id, content, userId) {
    console.log('send');
    const uid = this.loggedInUser.uid;
    const ref = this.afs.collection('messages').doc(id);
    return ref.update({
      message: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
        content,
        createdAt: Date.now(),
        userId
      })
    });
  }
```

But after this is done it keeps calling the init function that gets all of the messages and stores it in the message property

```html
  <ion-list lines="none">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let message of messages.message">
```

Comment: ngInit for which file? Your app.component.ts?

Comment: If ngInit is being called multiple times, its the parent of that component calling it multiple times and making multiple instances. The issue isnt with the child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your problem comes from one of theese behaviors:

1. When new value is assigned to messages.message, it may be equal as json, but still all objects have new pointers
2. Hence ngFor thinks that it got new array of different objects
3. Hence ngFor destroys old ion-item s and inits them again for 'new' objects, effectively recalling ngOnInit in each of them

Solution for this problem is adding trackBy to ngFor(read more here https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

Other possible behavior is that some of the methods you use return infinite Observable, solution to this problem is adding operators with take(1) or filter(someFilterFunc) to your pipe (for more info read here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md)

Comment: that didn't work...I know I'm doing something wrong here...there's something I'm missing.

Comment: I did two things to fix this problem...I implemented your suggestion with trackBy and I also noticed in my service I was implementing .OnSnapshot instead of .Get() on the doc.

Comment: Glad I could help you